# Windows DB2 9.7 FP8 - The request failed because private virtual memory could not be allocated. SQLSTATE=57011

Tags: db2

I have a Windows DB2 9.7 FP8 server running on Windows 2003 x86 that for some reason every time I launch Center Administrator or the CLI and try to connect to a database, I get the error "[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1219N The request failed because private virtual memory could not be allocated. SQLSTATE=57011".

Explanation:

The instance was unable to allocate enough private virtual memory to process the request. This may be a result of shared memory allocations made in other (unrelated) processes.

User response:

The problem may be corrected by: * Stopping other applications running on the machine, especially those that use large amounts of shared memory.

sqlcode: -1219

sqlstate: 57011

I have the same programs I've always had loaded on this server. I'm not sure when exactly the issue started, since I don't need to access the databases too often directly on server. I can launch Center Administrator from another server and connect remotely just fine.

I have over 1GB free memory.

I even rebooted server and changed boot.ini to include /3GB switch to give more memory (3GB instead of 2GB) to user processes.

I tried stopped a bunch of unused servers.

In short, I have no idea why this error is happening and if I can't resolve soon, will have to resort to upgrading to another FP or v10. I'm not sure uninstalling and reinstalling will work since I have active databases on the server?

Note: I'm not a DB2 expert and have to use it because SQL Server is too expensive and company has migrated off this platform. Go figure. Yet, everything I do with DB2 seems to be like hitting a break wall.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like an issue with your permissions and access control
The user you are setting up/or configuring an instance probably needs some more privilege.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v47r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_8.6.0.1%2Fawspitsvirtdb2admin.htm

> Installation fails with error “SQL1219N - The request failed because
>   private virtual memory could not be allocated.”
>
> During the master domain manager installation of DB2® on Windows, the
>   installation fails with the error “SQL1219N - The request failed
>   because private virtual memory could not be allocated.”
>
> Cause and solution The request failed because private virtual memory
>   could not be allocated. This can occur because the DB2 administrator
>   is not part of the Administrators group. You must add the DB2
>   administrator to the Administrators group by performing the following
>   steps:
>
> ```
> Cancel the installation wizard.
> Add the DB2 administrator, for example db2admin, to the Administrators group.
> Restart the workstation.
> Resume the installation.
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Do as Paul Bastide suggested, but before doing that permanent solution if you want to test, try "run as administrator" option on DB2 CLI. If you launch DB2 CLI as Administrator and application works then you can implement the permanent solution.